# Why one needs two Unevaluated to show 1+1 correctly in TreeForm?

Tags: front-end, evaluation, hold

The task sounds simple, give the tree plot of 1+1.
However, after some trying, I can only make this possible by using **two** `Unevaluated`.

```
TreeForm@Unevaluated@Unevaluated[1+1]
```

> [image: TreeForm Plot]

Since `Head@Unevaluate[1+1]` gives `Plus`, as expected,
my first guess is that one `Unevaluated` is enough, however

```
TreeForm@Unevaluated[1+1]
```

gives 2.

Looks like somehow the front-end evaluates `1+1` again during the plot.

So my question is how to understand this behavior? 
Or are there any other conceptually correct ways to do the plot?

Comment: `Unevaluated` is a function I never truly understand…

Comment: @xzczd You can find the explanation of Wagner's on P192. or [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Courseware/377/). However, even after reading these, the behavior I discribed really beats me.

Comment: `TreeForm@Inactive[Plus][1, 1]`

Comment: @yode Nope, this doesn't work. You may have a try.

Comment: To me, this seems a defect in `TreeForm`. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5722679/565518) for a previous discussion on this matter.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thanks a lot. That's nealy a same problem. I really hope some one could give a decisive explanation.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I've read the post and you've said what I want to say (and much more), I'm really happy about this:)

Comment: TreeForm@HoldForm[Plus][1, 1]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This issue is known and it is a defect of `TreeForm` like Leonid already said. Let me give an illustrative example that shows the same behavior. Let us assume you want a function that just returns its input unevaluated.

Without thinking we put down the function

```
f1[arg_] := HoldForm[arg]
```

Now, what seems like a clever idea has one flaw: when you evaluate `f1[1+1]` the `1+1` is already evaluated before `f1` is called, because this is how the standard evaluation in *Mathematica* works. It evaluates all arguments of a function. Let us look at the `Trace`:

```
Trace[f1[1+1]]
(* {{1+1,2},f1[2],2} *)
```

You see, the `1+1` is turned into 2 and after that, `f1` is called. There is no chance your `HoldForm` could do anything useful.

But now you say, I can prevent exactly this evaluation by using `Unevaluated`. This is by the way the use-case for `Unevaluated`: You want to stop the evaluation of an argument to make that it reaches the body of your function unharmed:

```
Trace[f1[Unevaluated[1+1]]]
(* {f1[1+1],1+1} *)
```

Perfect. But let's assume you rather want to turn your expression into a `String` instead of returning it with `HoldForm`. No problem you will say, because now you know how it works:

```
f2[arg_] := ToString[arg]
f2[Unevaluated[1+1]]
(* 2 *)
```

You don't have to think hard why this doesn't work when you have read carefully up to here. On every function call, the arguments are evaluated if this evaluation was not prevented by something. Let us look at the trace:

```
Trace[f2[Unevaluated[1+1]]]
(* {f2[1+1],ToString[1+1],{1+1,2},ToString[2],2} *)
```

You see the `1+1` makes it unharmed to `ToString` but gets evaluated before `ToString` does its action. How could we prevent this? We could wrap another layer of `Unevaluated` around our expression:

```
Trace[f2[Unevaluated@Unevaluated[1+1]]]
(* {f2[Unevaluated[1+1]],ToString[Unevaluated[1+1]],ToString[1+1],1 + 1} *)
```

The first `Unevaluated` brings our expression unharmed inside `f2`, the second `Unevaluated` makes it survive the call of `ToString`.

Something similar happens in `TreeForm` and it is the reason, why a double `Unevaluated` works.

#### The final question

> Why did `f1` work then? There, the one `Unevaluated` should be eaten by the `f1` call and `HoldForm` should evaluate `1+1` just like `ToString` did.

Exactly, instead of it doesn't because it has another way to say *I don't evaluate my arguments*.

```
Attributes[HoldForm]
(* {HoldAll,Protected} *)
```

The function `HoldForm` has the attribute `HoldAll` which says: "I don't evaluate any of my arguments". And it is true, if you think about it with your knowledge now, the only reason why this

```
In[22]:= HoldForm[1+1]
Out[22]= 1+1
```

returns `1+1`, has to be something special about `HoldForm`. Therefore, here comes a third function that concludes the explanation:

```
SetAttributes[f3,{HoldAll}];
f3[arg_]:=ToString[Unevaluated[arg]]
f3[1+1]
(* 1 + 1 *)
```

Comment: It is not easy to prevent evaluation inside a function that has the
attribute `HoldAll`. For example : `SetAttributes[f3, {HoldAll}];
f3[arg_] := ToString[Unevaluated[#]] & @ arg;
f3[1 + 1]` gives `2`. That is to say `f[x]` and `f[#]& @ x` have different behaviours.

Comment: Exactly and why is that? Because `#&` is another function that is called and that *leaks evaluation*! Look [here](http://hastebin.com/yopivusoxe.pas). In general, Leonid has a bunch of very advanced answers around the topic evaluation control, but they might be a bit too difficult for beginners. This is why I wrote up an answer to this question, because it gave me the opportunity to discuss a very small detail that might lead to people thinking about this topic.

Comment: AFAK, front-end is responsible for these formatting stuff. So it's a bug of the front-end?

Comment: It's not entirely clear. On the one hand, if you use a LinkSnooper to monitor the communication between FronEnd and Kernel, you clearly see that the kernel sends the wrong result back. On the other hand, if you use `math` in a terminal session, you can call `TreeFrom[Unevaluated[1+1]]` and it gives you back a tree-form where the `1+1` is not evaluated. But the `Unevaluated` isn't stripped either. Therefore, I think the issue is in the kernel, but the kernel behaves differently when it is attached to a graphical FrontEnd.

Comment: @halirutan Thanks a lot, I get it, and I'm sorry for my late reply. I wasn't informed by your comment.