# Why Unevaluated doesn't work on unheld side of Rule/RuleDelayed?

Tags: evaluation, core-language, hold

`Unevaluated` is a function that I never truly understand, and here's one of the cases confusing me:

```
Unevaluated[1 + 1] -> 3
(* 2 -> 3 *)
```

Same thing happens on right side of `Rule` and left side of `RuleDelayed (:>)` i.e. `Unevaluated` affects none of the unheld sides of `Rule`/`RuleDelayed`:

```
2 -> Unevaluated[1 + 2]
(* 2 -> 3 *)
Unevaluated[1 + 1] :> 3
(* 2 :> 3 *)
```

`Trace` shows that `Unevaluated` does seem to work for once, but after that,`Rule` evaluates its left side again:

```
Unevaluated[1 + 1] -> 3 // Trace
```

[image]

No matter how many `Unevaluated` exists, `Rule` will tenaciously evaluate again and again, until the `Unevaluated`s are all killed:

```
Unevaluated@Unevaluated@Unevaluated@Unevaluated[1 + 1] -> 3 // Trace
```

[image]

My questions are:

1. Is this just a individual case i.e. a special behavior of `Rule`/`RuleDelayed`, or there's a class of function that shares the same behavior?
2. Why `Rule`/`RuleDelayed` is designed to behave like this? Is there any deep meaning?

Comment: I assume that `Unevaluated` is only kept until `Rule` recieves its arguments (as the documentation states), but afterwards arguments are evaluated normally as `Rule` does not have attribute `HoldAll` or similar. Compare with `f[x_] := x;f[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]` which also returns 2.

Comment: @IstvánZachar But for your case `f[Unevaluated@Unevaluated[1 + 1]]` will return `Unevaluated[1 + 1]`.

Comment: Oh, I see your point now. Then I guess this behaviour is specific for rules, i.e. entities that specify rewrite processes, necessary for the `Replace` family. Furthermore, `Association` behaves similar (while `DirectedEdge` does not)

Comment: Related: [(110490)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110490/why-one-needs-two-unevaluated-to-show-11-correctly-in-treeform).

Comment: @Xavier It's that question that motivates me to ask this :)

Comment: @xzczd Yes, that was my guess when I saw you edited that question :)

Comment: Duplicate question on Stack Overflow: [(6267143)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6267143/618728)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Maybe you can migrate that post to this site so we can mark my question as a duplicate, or write an answer for my question? Actually here comes another duplicate…: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124249/1871

Comment: @xzczd Migrations of old questions are no longer possible.  Perhaps Leonid and Alexey could be convinced to repost their answers here.

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice analysis about the issue at hand at Stack Overflow [6267143](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6267143/712498) (the finding of Mr.Wizard). I'd redirect anyone to read the answers there for those are very enlightening. Here I only provide a recap of the essentials as a community wiki.

> "`Unevaluated` gets stripped when it occurs as the outermost wrapper in
>   a rule. This is how `Unevaluated` works, i.e. `Unevaluated` is not a
>   regular symbol which evaluates anything." ([Sasha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/594376/sasha))

`Unevaluated` is an inert symbol without values or definitions, only attributes `HoldAllComplete` and `Protected`. Therefore, nothing is performed on it when appears naked, e.g. `Unevaluated[1+1]` remains as it is. However, it's behaviour is not typical to those of inert heads. When the evaluator, traversing an expression tree from top to leafs, meets with `Unevaluated`, it strips it. Then, when passing up the tree at the end of evaluation, "the Unevaluated wrappers are restored for those parts of expression where no applicable rules were found" ([Leonid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6269991/712498)) (e.g. undefined functions like `f`). This basically means the followings:

1. If `Unevaluated` appears within a function that does nothing, it is ultimately retained, as no evaluation is done at all:

   `In[1]:= ClearAll[f]; f[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]`

   `Out[1]= f[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]`
2. If `Unevaluated` appears within a function that has rules defined for processing its arguments, it gets stripped as the evaluator digs in. Note however, that the number of `Unevaluated`s being stripped depends on the number of evaluations that subexpression will participate in (an answer to the comment of [xzczd](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110499/why-unevaluated-doesnt-work-on-unheld-side-of-rule-ruledelayed#comment299760_110499) above). (This is not a number that can trivially be calculated beforehand.)

   `In[2]:= 1 -> Unevaluated[1 + 1]`

   `Out[2]= 1 -> 2`

   or an even simpler example:

   `In[3]:= Identity[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]`

   `Out[3]= 2`
3. If `Unevaluated` appears within a function that holds its arguments, it gets stripped but the arguments are still held per the attribute(s) of the function (RuleDelayed in this example):

   `In[4]:= 1 :> Unevaluated[1 + 1]`

   `Out[4]= 1 :> 1 + 1`

### Summary

This is no bug, and not some specific behaviour of `Rule` or `RuleDelayed`. Due to the generally unknown number of evaluations a subexpression goes through during evaluation, `Unevaluated` should not be used as a general method to shield evaluation -- use `Hold` for that. And read the [full analysis here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6267143/712498).

Comment: "This is …… not some specific behaviour of `Rule` or `RuleDelayed`." I'm sorry but I don't agree. If so, can you build a function that has the same behavior? (Typically the last example in my question. )

Comment: @xzczd Yes and no. In one hand, `RuleDelayed` is specific, but on the other hand, you can simulate it's evaluation sequence, as Leonid did in his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6269991/712498). BTW, feel free to edit in, as this is a CW.

Comment: A very simple example of `Rule` specialty: compare  `Rule[Unevaluated@Unevaluated@x, Unevaluated@Unevaluated@y]` and `f1[Unevaluated@Unevaluated@x, Unevaluated@Unevaluated@y]`.