# Help me understand this behaviour of the standard evaluation procedure with `Unevaluated`

Tags: evaluation, hold

Wagner's book says that, in the Standard Evaluation Procedure,

> 16. If no applicable rules where found and any of the part_i has the head `Unevaluated`, restore that head.

This explains why `h[Unevaluated[RandomReal[]]]` or plain `Unevaluated[RandomReal[]]` are inert.

However consider this:

```
plus[x_, y_] := x + y
```

Then

(A) `plus[1., Unevaluated[RandomReal[]]]` gives `1.81318`

but

`a = Unevaluated@Unevaluated[RandomReal[]]; plus[1., a]` (one level of `Unevaluated` is stripped by `Set`, I think)

gives `1. + Unevaluated[RandomReal[]]`. Shouldn't this behave exactly like (A)?

**Aside**

How come that after both `a = Unevaluated[RandomReal[]]` and `a = Unevaluated@Unevaluated[RandomReal[]]`, `OwnValues@a` gives

`{HoldPattern[a] :> RandomReal[]}`

when clearly the second assignment behaves differently, e.g. in the example given herein?

**Aside 2**

If I use `Plus`, `Plus[1., Unevaluated[RandomReal[]]]` and `a = Unevaluated@Unevaluated[RandomReal[]]; Plus[1., a]` both give `1. + Unevaluated[RandomReal[]]` as expected.

Comment: And if instead you define `plus = Plus`, then `plus[1., Unevaluated[RandomReal[]]]` evaluates to `1. + Unevaluated[RandomReal[]]`, so it has something to do with finding `DownValues` of `plus` (in the sense that it is using a rule to replace `plus[ stuff]` with `somethingelse[ stuff ]` during which `stuff` gets evaluated perhaps, because it has to match `stuff` to the pattern rather than just the head `plus`.

Comment: @march That "`plus = Plus`, then `plus[1., Unevaluated[RandomReal[]]]` evaluates to `1. + Unevaluated[RandomReal[]]`" is consistent with my understanding of evaluation: heads are evaluated first, so my "Aside 2" applies here.

Comment: I think `Unevaluated` acts as stated only when it appears explicitly as the argument. You can't set an expression wrapped `Unevaluated` to a variable and make it act the same way.

Comment: `OwnValues` in _Aside_ looks the same in both cases, but `a` doesn't behave the same; definition `a := RandomReal[]` is equivalent to the first.

Comment: Essentially the same question as this one: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110499/1871, just try `a // OwnValues // Trace`. Sadly no one has answered that question so currently this can't be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Related: [(25266)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25266/121)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe we can explain this behavior by referencing:

- [Working with Unevaluated Expressions - Robby Villegas](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Courseware/377/)

> **Unevaluated must be wrapper before argument evaluation, not after, else it isn't stripped.**
>
> Recall our discussion of the over-arching evaluator, and the fact that
>   your inputs and commands have two stages:  their original form, and
>   the reduced form with arguments all evaluated.
>
> Unevaluated is not meant to be a function or stable data type.  It is
>   to be used as a wrapper on an argument in stage 1, before argument
>   evaluation.  It is a signal to the evaluator to suppress the usual
>   evaluation of that argument.
>   ...
>
> Those of you who have experimented with Unevaluated have found that in some situations it doesn't vanish.  This makes it seem confusing and inconsistent, like Sequence.
>   ...
>
> The subtle and confusing situation where Unevaluated persists is when an argument did not originally have a head of Unevaluated, but became Unevaluated[whatever] after argument evaluation finished.

`Unevaluated` does not appear explicitly as the head of one of the arguments in `plus[1., a]`, therefore `Unevaluated[RandomReal[]]` is inserted into `Plus` verbatim to become `1. + Unevaluated[RandomReal[]]`, which evaluates for the reason you described yourself in a comment:

> There is no rule for `Plus[1, Unevaluated[RandomReal[]]]` (i.e. for `Plus[1, RandomReal[]]` with `RandomReal[]` *not* evaluated to a number).

#### Aside 1

*Revision*

As [xzczd](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1871/xzczd) noted in a comment `Unevaluated` is stripped from the right-hand-side of `RuleDelayed` when it (the rule expression) is evaluated.  ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6267143))

It appears in [`Definition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Definition.html):

```
Definition[a]
```

> ```
> a = Unevaluated[RandomReal[]]
> ```

Using [my `step` evaluation function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1447/121) with `OwnValues` works too:

```
OwnValues[a] // step
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[a] :> Unevaluated[RandomReal[]]}     (* HoldForm *)
> ```

The undocumented `` Language`ExtendedFullDefinition `` returns the rules in a `` Language`DefinitionList `` container which has `HoldAll`:

```
Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[a]
```

> ```
> Language`DefinitionList[HoldForm[a] -> 
>   {OwnValues -> HoldPattern[a] :> 
>      Unevaluated[RandomReal[]], SubValues -> {}, 
>    UpValues -> {}, DownValues -> {}, NValues -> {}, 
>    FormatValues -> {}, DefaultValues -> {}, 
>    Messages -> {}, Attributes -> {}}]
> ```

Comment: Well, as to the aside 1, as mentioned in the comment above, I think the issue here is just "`Rule` or `RuleDelayed` will strip all `Unevaluated` when evaluated" i.e. those `Unevaluated`s are actually stored in `OwnValues` but are simply "killed" when `OwnValues@a` is executed. Just try `a // OwnValues // Trace`.

Comment: @xzczd Good catch!  I guess that's why ``Language`DefinitionList`` has `HoldAll`.

Comment: I have read this theory more than 20+ times,but I cannot understand your `must be wrapper before argument evaluation`.So this theory can explain why `Plus[2, Unevaluated[3]]` can get result,but `Plus[2, Unevaluated[RandomReal[]]]` not?

Comment: @yode I am falling asleep.  I will have to answer tomorrow.  Please remind me as I will probably forget.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing..Good night. :)

Comment: @yode If you are here now please comment; I would like to discuss this in [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/wolfram-mathematica).