# How to get such rule with a elegant method

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists:

```
list={{1,2,3,5},{5,3,9,11,12},{5,9,10,16}};
list2={{7,89},{96,5},{-6,-98}};
```

This is the expected result.

> ```
> {{1->{7,89},2->{7,89},3->{7,89},5->{7,89}},
>  {5->{96,5},3->{96,5},9->{96,5},11->{96,5},12->{96,5}},
>  {5->{-6,-98},9->{-6,-98},10->{-6,-98},16->{-6,-98}}}
> ```

This is my current try.

```
Thread /@ 
 Thread[Rule[list, 
   MapIndexed[ConstantArray[list2[[First[#2]]], Length[#1]] &, list]]]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Tuples /@ Thread[list -> List /@ list2]
```

> ```
> {
>  {1 -> {7, 89}, 2 -> {7, 89}, 3 -> {7, 89}, 5 -> {7, 89}},
>  {5 -> {96, 5}, 3 -> {96, 5}, 9 -> {96, 5}, 11 -> {96, 5}, 12 -> {96, 5}},
>  {5 -> {-6, -98}, 9 -> {-6, -98}, 10 -> {-6, -98}, 16 -> {-6, -98}}
> }
> ```

Comment: Good lesson to me.Thanks.

Comment: @yode You're welcome :^)

Comment: I mean,your usage of `Tuples` and `List/@` astonish me. :)

Comment: @yode I was just having good-natured fun with your typo.  I am glad you learned from this example.  Quite a few functions work on heads other than `List` which is quite handy, e.g. [(1312)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1312/121)

Comment: It's not a typo.I just cannot hold the temper of my English sometimes. :)

Comment: Killer. Would be great to compile a list of such one-liners to show the power of functional approach.

Answer (score 10):

```
MapIndexed[# -> list2[[#2[[1]]]] &, list, {2}]
```

or

```
ReplacePart[list, {i_, j_} :> list[[i, j]] -> list2[[i]]]
```

Comment: Wow,thanks.This is very concise method,too.

Answer (score 9):

```
Thread /@ Thread[list -> Hold /@ list2] // ReleaseHold
Thread /@ Thread[list → Unevaluated /@ list2] /. a_ → b_ -> a -> b
Thread /@ Thread[list -> $ /@ list2] /. $ -> (# &)
```

As to the reason why I used `RightArrow` as a medium in the second solution, you may want to read [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110499/1871).

Comment: +1)Impressive...BTY,how do you type that second $\to$?

Comment: @yode I just transformed `\[RightArrow]` with [M.SE editor](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1044/1871) :) .

Comment: You can also type ESC SPACE - > ESC.

Answer (score 9):

Another way to use `Thread`:

```
Thread[#, List, 1] & /@ Thread[list -> list2]
```

> ```
> {{1 -> {7, 89}, 2 -> {7, 89}, 3 -> {7, 89}, 5 -> {7, 89}}, 
>  {5 -> {96, 5}, 3 -> {96, 5}, 9 -> {96, 5}, 11 -> {96, 5}, 12 -> {96, 5}}, 
>  {5 -> {-6, -98}, 9 -> {-6, -98}, 10 -> {-6, -98}, 16 -> {-6, -98}}}
> ```

Answer (score 9):

`MapThread` + `Outer`:

```
MapThread[Outer[Rule, ##, 1] &, {list, List /@ list2}]
```

Obfuscatory:

[image]

or

```
o = (\[FivePointedStar] \[Function] \[FivePointedStar] -> #2) /@ # & @@@ ({##}\[Transpose]) &;
o[list, list2]
```

Comment: Upvote for *Star*. :)

Answer (score 7):

```
MapThread[Map[Function[x, Rule[x, #2]], #1] &, {list, list2}]
```

Comment: Joke version: `MapThread[(#0[[0]] @@ {#0[[1, 2]] -> #2}) /@ # &, {list, list2}] `

Answer (score 6):

I'm late to this party, but I don't see any other answer like this:

```
 helper[{u_, v_}] := Rule[#, v] & /@ u
 helper /@ Transpose[{list, list2}]
```

> ```
> {{1 -> {7, 89}, 2 -> {7, 89}, 3 -> {7, 89}, 5 -> {7, 89}}, 
>  {5 -> {96, 5}, 3 -> {96, 5}, 9 -> {96, 5}, 11 -> {96, 5}, 12 -> {96, 5}}, 
>  {5 -> {-6, -98}, 9 -> {-6, -98}, 10 -> {-6, -98}, 16 -> {-6, -98}}}
> ```

This seems to me to be a nice, simple way of solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This works, and it is easy to understand:

Flatten[MapThread[
  Function[{l1, l2}, Map[{# -> l2} &, l1]], {list, list2}], 1]