# Do not understand evaluation order of ReplaceAll

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, evaluation, core-language, hold

```
{x, x^2, Length@x, Subsets[x]} /. x -> {1, 2, 3}   
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 9}, 0, {{}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}} *)
```

with error  [image]

**What does it mean?**

**Why `^` evaluates, but `Length` not?**

**Why there is correct result of `Subsets` in output, but raised error?**

---

UPD:
Many thanks to all for the detailed explanations!
Still the question was interesting

Comment: `Length` evaluates to be `0`; check `Length@x`. Not sure what you mean when you say it does not evaluate. Also, the argument of `Subset` has to be a list, and currently it is not, hence the error.

Comment: I don't understand. Does `Length` and `Subsets` evaluate after replacement? Then x will be List!  And why we see right result of `Subsets`?

Comment: Why should they evaluate after the replacement? I just explained with the example; `Length@x` gives `0`. Is it possible that you want to write `foo[n_] := {x, x^2, Length@Range@n, Subsets[Range@n]} /. x -> Range@n` and then `foo[3]`?

Comment: No need to be reopen, but reasons for close _"is unlikely to help any future visitors, or else it is easily found in the documentation"_  is absolutely unconvincing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### What's happening on your code

You can check the evaluation with [`TracePrint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TracePrint.html). You will see that the Left hand side does get evaluated before the replacement. At that first evaluation `x^2` returns unchanged, `Subsets[x]` gives an error and also returns unchanged. `Length[x]` evaluates and returns `0`.

```
TracePrint[
{x, x^2, Length@x, Subsets[x]} /. x -> {1, 2, 3}   
]
```

> [image]

You could have investigated the error with Show Stack Trace.

[image]

[image]

### One of many solutions to what you ask

You could avoid the left hand side been evaluated by using [`Hold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold.html) and only [`ReleaseHold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReleaseHold.html) after [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) (`/.`) has evaluated. That will avoid the error from trying to evaluate `Subsets[x]` and have `Length` return the length of `{1, 2, 3}` (3) instead of the length of `x` (0).

```
ReleaseHold[
     Hold[{x, x^2, Length@x, Subsets[x]}] /. x -> {1, 2, 3}   
]
```

[image]

This does evaluate in the order you want

> [image]

### Answers

This is a rather abstract and advanced issue, it's ok to find it complicated. I struggled articulating a precise answer myself.

##### What does it mean?

It means you need to consider in which order thigs are evaluated, and how many times that happens. You can control that order in many ways. See [Evaluation Control](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/guide/EvaluationControl.html).

##### Why ^ evaluates, but Length not?

Both evaluate. `Length[x]` evaluates to `0`. `Power[x,2]` evaluates but first returns unchanged, and remains unchanged until `ReplaceAll` evaluates changing `x` for `{1,2,3}`. Then `Power[{1,2,3},2]` evaluates to  `{1,4,9}`.

##### Why there is correct result of Subsets in output, but raised error?

Because it first tries to evaluate `Subsets[x]`, gives an error and returns unchanged. Then `ReplaceAll` evaluates, and now `Subsets[{1, 2, 3}]` can evaluate correctly and give an output different from the input.

Comment: But why `Power` evaluates?

Comment: @lesobrod I have added further explanations. Does this answer your question now?

Comment: "`Power[x,2]` remains unevaluated. " To be precise, it _returns_ unevaluated i.e. the output is the same as the input.

Comment: @xzczd I now have *"`Power[x,2]` evaluates but returns unchanged, and remains unchanged until `ReplaceAll` evaluates."*. Would you agree with that? Feel free to directly edit the text to make it more precise, if you wish .

Comment: @rhermans  This is exactly what I expected from community, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Let me repeat again:

> If a function doesn't have a `HoldAll`/`HoldFirst`/`HoldRest`/`HoldAllComplete` attribute, its argument(s) will always be evaluated before going **into** the function.

`ReplaceAll` (`/.)` doesn't have such attribute, so the whole `{x, x^2, Length@x, Subsets[x]}` evaluates before the replacement happens. (The order is from left to right, BTW. ) This can be checked with `Trace`:

```
Trace[{x, x^2, Length[x], Subsets[x]} /. x -> {1, 2, 3}]
```

[image]

If you want to check the evaluation of `x` and `x^2`, set `TraceOriginal -> True`, the output will be a bit more involved, though.

As we can see, `Length@x` evaluates to `0`. This is expected. As mentioned in **Details** section of document of `Length`:

> `Length[expr]` returns `0` whenever `AtomQ[expr]` is `True`.

`Subsets[x]` evaluates to itself with a warning `Subsets::normal`. Since the `Subsets[x]` is still there, once the replacement happens, it'll become `Subsets[{1, 2, 3}]` and further evaluates to the desired output.

Finally, in addition to the `Hold` & `ReleaseHold` technique shown in rhermans' answer, another (more advanced) way to adjust the evaluation order is to use `Unevaluated`:

```
Unevaluated@{x, x^2, Length[x], Subsets[x]} /. x -> {1, 2, 3}
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 9}, 3, {{}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}} *)
```

Comment: +1, can you explain why `Unevaluated` is more advanced and how is different?

Comment: @rhermans `Unevaluated` is a special function, it owns some properties that cannot be explained in usual way. A simple example: `f[a][[1]]` returns `a`, but `Unevaluated[a][[1]]` returns the input with a warning. I'd recommend reading this: https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/377/ Some other posts showing its special behavior: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110490/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110499/1871